# How to sum subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL statement that works perfectly. However I now need a total as designated in bold square brackets/parenthesis below.

```
SELECT f.fid, r.tid, r.tbd, r.tbc, r.tc, r.tname, r.category,
      SUM(`time`) AS `totaltime`,
      SUM(`points`) AS `points`,
      (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points),0) FROM Primes WHERE zid = r.zid AND wid = r.wid AND s_id = 38) AS `cl`,
      (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points),0) FROM Primes WHERE zid = r.zid AND wid = r.wid AND s_id = 34) AS `sp`,

      **[sum points + climb + sprint] AS pointstotal**

      FROM teams f
      JOIN results r
      ON f.wid = r.wid
      WHERE r.rank <= 3 AND r.id = '254293' AND r.category = 'C'
      AND r.fin = '1'
      GROUP BY f.fid
      ORDER BY pointstotal DESC
```

I have tried many different permutations etc and multiple references in other questions but I just cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to move your query into a subquery, and then add those columns.

```
SELECT fid, tid, tbd, tbc, tc, tname, category, totaltime, 
        points, cl, sp, points + cl + sp AS pointstotal
FROM (
    SELECT f.fid, r.tid, r.tbd, r.tbc, r.tc, r.tname, r.category,
          SUM(`time`) AS `totaltime`,
          SUM(`points`) AS `points`,
          (SELECT SUM(points) FROM Primes WHERE zid = r.zid AND wid = r.wid AND s_id = 38) AS `cl`,
          (SELECT SUM(points) FROM Primes WHERE zid = r.zid AND wid = r.wid AND s_id = 34) AS `sp`
    FROM teams f
    JOIN results r
    ON f.wid = r.wid
    WHERE r.rank <= 3 AND r.id = '254293' AND r.category = 'C'
    AND r.fin = '1'
    GROUP BY f.fid
) AS x
ORDER BY pointstotal DESC
```

But I generally dislike correlated subqueries, I prefer joins, and then you don't need another level

```
SELECT SELECT f.fid, r.tid, r.tbd, r.tbc, r.tc, r.tname, r.category,
        SUM(time) AS totaltime, SUM(points) AS points,
        cl, sp, SUM(POINTS) + cl + sp AS totalpoints
FROM teams AS f
JOIN results AS r ON f.wid = r.wid
JOIN (
    SELECT zid, wid, SUM(IF(s_id = 38, points, 0)) AS cl, SUM(IF(s_id = 34, points, 0)) AS sp
    FROM Primes
    GROUP BY zid, wid
) AS p ON p.zid = r.zid AND p.wid = r.wid
WHERE r.rank <= 3 AND r.id = '24293' AND r.category = 'C' AND r.fin = '1'
GROUP BY f.fid
ORDER BY pointstotal DESC
```

Comment: Wow! I thought it might be complicated and the correlated subqueries makes more sense to me over the joins. Presumably the joins would be faster than the correlated subqueries?

Comment: In this case it might not be, because the subquery processes all the rows in `Primes`, not just the ones that match the rows being selected in the main query. So you'll need to test them to see how efficient they are.